# how to show text box value for already selected item in dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

i have a page name is edit_new_residancy.ctp here everthing is working but i am stucking a problem in that page i have a dropdown list housing allowance which accept cash or by company i want when cash option is already selected then automatacally a text box will be show with the value. code is blow here

```
<?php if($company_type==LABOUR_TYPE) { ?>
    <div id="salary_detail_section">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"> <h4>Salary Detail:</h4> </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
             <?php echo $this->Form-
               >input('basic_salary',array('required'=>false,'class'=>"form-
               control",  'placeholder'=>"Basic Salary","label"=>false)); 
             ?>
            </div>
           </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('housing_allowance_type',
                array('required'=>false,'class'=>"form-control",
               'id'=>"ApplicationAllowanceType",'type'=>"select",
               'options'=>$housing_allowance_type,"label"=>false)); 
             ?>
           </div>
         </div>

       <div class="col-md-6" id="cash_box" style="display:none;">
          <div class="form-group"> 
             <?php echo $this->Form->input('housing_allowance',
                   array('required'=>false,'class'=>"form-control",
                   "label"=>false,'placeholder'=>"Enter amount",
                   'id'=>'house_allowance')); 
             ?>
          </div>
       </div>

       </div>
       </div> 
       <?php } ?>
```

my jquery code in same file which is blow here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ApplicationAllowanceType').change(function(){
        $type = $(this).val();
        if($type==2)
        {
            $('#cash_box').show('slow');
        }else{
            $('#cash_box').hide('slow');
        }
    });
  });


 </script>
```

i am getting correct value in dropdownlist which is cash($type==2) but i am not getting text box(#cash_box) automatacally.a very thanks in advance.

Comment: add the rendered html

Comment: sorry can you explain me

Comment: checck if cash_box id is unique

Comment: how we can check cash_box id unique . can you explain by code